# rm -r versus rm -d?

Tags: command-line, bash, rm

I see a lot of resources on `rm -r` but almost nothing on `rm -d` even though the `d` flag is apparently all about deleting directories.

What is the difference between the two exactly? Is `rm -d` the same as `rmdir`? Is it "safer" than `rm -r`?

Comment: According to the man page, `-d` will only remove empty directories. `-r` doesn't care.

Comment: Afaik `-r` only doesn't care if also `-f` is set

Comment: @derHugo `-r` is recursive, it repeatedly deleted the contents. `-f` just means don't prompt the user

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tried both commands and here are my conclusions:

- `rm -d` works just like `rmdir` (unless there's something going on with links or something like that).
- `rm -r` deletes the target directory and recursively deletes everything inside that directory (including non-empty directories and files of any type)

So the difference is pretty clear. There's no doubt that `rm -r` is a really dangerous command that should be used very carefuly (Example: `rm -rf /` can potentialy delete your system; or `rm -rf *` could delete your current project), while `rm -d` will only let you delete empty directories

### Warning

Remember that `rm -rd` is a valid command and it will work like `rm -r`, so be careful.

Comment: You're not wrong about `rm -rf /` being dangerous, however there are protections that help to prevent you from deleting your file system, and you would have to be actively malicious to provide the proper arguments necessary to erase the root system directory.

Comment: I know that you have to provide the `--no-preserve-root` option to do that kind of thing, but the point is pretty clear.

Comment: `rm -d` doesn't remove an empty directory on my system with coreutils 6.9 (not Ubuntu), while `rmdir` does. Not sure why.

Comment: @FranciscoGallegoSalido iirc, POSIX states that you shouldn’t be able to remove the current working directory, so it could be argued that `rm -rf /` shouldn’t work because it would remove the directory you are currently in. Sun Microsystems took this approach in Solaris, so Solaris derivatives implement this afaik. Then again, Linux isn’t Unix and cares less and less about POSIX I feel.

Comment: @forquare Ok, let's say `rm -rf *` is dangerous, better example? I'm going to edit it.

Comment: Oh that kind of scares me actually, I would assume `rm -rf *` deletes everything in the current working directory. Is that not what it does? Or is it supposed to be `rm -rf ./*` for that?

Comment: @ArukaJ Both are valid expressions (at least in Ubuntu 16.04).

Answer (score 1):

A difference between `rm -rd` and `rm -rf` is that the former will prompt you before deleting a write-protected file or directory, while the latter will go ahead and delete write-protected files without prompting if it can do so. While `rm -rd` and `rm -rf` are both recursive and potentially dangerous if directed to the wrong directory, the former provides a little more protection against doing something you really didn't want to do.